# Understand the following pointer code written in c

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I am trying to understand a piece of code and I am not a very experienced programmer. Can you please help me understand what is meant by the statement A here?

```
 dImage *filterdImage;     
 float *lp = filterdImage->pixels[0];//Statement A, what's going on?
```

Here, dImage is a struct defined as :

```
 typedef struct dImage{
 int width; 
 int height;
 float **pixels;
}
```

Comment: Your sample code doesn't even compile.

Comment: Apologies. I had mistakenly written int *lp instead of float *lp here. Edit now.

Comment: filterdImage is declared as a variable, then used like a pointer.. that won't compile...

Comment: This still won't run. The -> operator is used on pointers, and 'dImage' is not a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filterdImage->pixels` accesses the `pixels` member in `filterdImage`.

`filterdImage->pixels[0]` accesses the first element in the array that `pixels` points to. Since `pixels` is of type `float**`, the elements are of type `float*`.

`float *lp = filterdImage->pixels[0]` assigns that pointer to `lp`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Actually it is.

Comment: It wasn't when you posted the answer or I the comment.

Comment: @zenith thanks! If now I want to change `float **pixels` in the struct, to 
`int pixels[10][10]`, any idea how I should modify statement A?

Comment: @st1046 Then change the type of `lp` to `int*` as well.

Comment: @zenith something like : 
`int * lp = filterdImage-> pixels[0][0]` ?

Comment: @zenith, since pixels is no more a pointer, but just a 2D array, is it still okay to just say `int * lp = filterdImage-> pixels[0]` ?

Answer (score 2):

After you fix the syntax errors, this code is pretty straightforward. The structure:

```
typedef struct dImage{
    int width; 
    int height;
    float **pixels;
}
```

Contains an image in which each pixel is a float (perhaps in grayscale, like an X-Ray or telescope image). The double ** means that the pixel array itself is not a compact 2D-array, but an array-of-arrays; that is, it's an array of lines, each of which is an array of pixels (there are two different ways to do 2D-arrays in C).

```
float *lp = filterdImage->pixels[0];
```

sets the variable `lp` to point to the first line of pixels. `pixels[1]` would point to the second line, etc. Now you can access each pixel of the line with `lp[0]`, `lp[1]`, etc.